# write a program in java to Check if a sub string is Present in a Given String or not without using array

Tags: java

```
String s,sub,s1="",s2="";
int l,l1,n;
int k = 0;
char ch,ch1;
System.out.println("enter String");
s = sc.next();
System.out.println("enter sub String");
sub = sc.next();
l  = s.length();
l1 = sub.length();
for(int i =0;i<l1;i++)
{
    ch = sub.charAt(i);
    for(int j = 0;j<l;j++)
    {
        ch1 = s.charAt(j);
        if((int)ch-(int)ch1==0)
        {

            k=1;
            s1 = sub.substring(i+1);
            int l2 = s1.length();
            s2 = s.substring(j+1);
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
}
int l2 = s1.length();
String s3 = s2.substring(0,l2);
if(s1.equals(s3))
    System.out.println("present");
else
    System.out.println("not present");   
}
```

This program is not giving correct output

```
    input:Hello
    enter subString
    lo
    output: not present
    **expected output**
    input:
    enter string :Hello
    enter subString: lo
    output: present
    its giving correct output for other input
    input:
    enter String:hello
    enter sub String: ello
    output:present
    **one more example**
    enter String
    hello
    enter:sub String
    l
    output:present
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `contains(String)` to compare and `trim()` to remove blank characters from start and end of string?

```
String s,sub;

System.out.println("enter String");
s = sc.next().trim();

System.out.println("enter sub String");
sub = sc.next().trim();

if(s.contains(sub)){

    System.out.println("present");

}else{

    System.out.println("not present"); 

}
```

**EDIT**

You could compare char by char.

```
boolean isSubString = false;

for(int i = 0; i <= s.length() - sub.length(); i++) {

    isSubString = true;

    for(int j = 0; j < sub.length(); j++) {

        if(s.charAt(i+j) != sub.charAt(j)) {

            isSubString = false;
            break;

        }

    }

    if(isSubString == true) {

        break;

    }

}

System.out.println(isSubString);
```

Comment: we have to do this program without using contain( ) function

Comment: but your answer is useful sir

Comment: @ManjotSingh I edited my answer, look at it. And please, next time when you post a question, tell us all conditions.